# How to know wheather two dates are equal or not in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the row count where id and dates match. I have run this query in mysql it works fine

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Id = '587762' && RequestDate = '2017-03-10'
```

But when executing in php it not returning the desired result. This is my php file

```
    <?php
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=personDB','root','');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'){
        $Id = $_GET['ID'];
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['date']));
        $row_count = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id = '$Id' AND RequestDate = '$date'")->fetchColumn();
        if($row_count > 0){
            $response = false;
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        else{
            $response = true;
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
    ?>
```

RequestDate has no time component. I am checking it in postman and giving the value which already exist it should return false but it's returning true always.

Comment: Why do you set `$response = false` when a row is returned?

Comment: What is the value of `$_GET['date']`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to do some other things when there is values of the same id and date

Comment: @justbaron date not time component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$row_count` doesn't contain the amount of rows, but the result of the query. Try this:

```
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
$row_count = $result->fetchColumn();
```

The `fetchColumn()` function gets the first column of the first row of the result.

Comment: I have used count

Comment: Yes, you used `count(*)` in your query, but that doesn't mean that the result of the query is equal to to `count(*)`. What if your query was `SELECT COUNT(*), somethingElse FROM table`?

Comment: I don't want the first column of the first row of the result. I want total row count

Comment: But the query returns a 'table' with 1 row and 1 column. The column name in this table is probably 'COUNT(*)'. The cell in this table contains the total row count.

Comment: I am getting error on fetchColumn "Call to a member function fetchColumn() on boolean in"

Comment: Here is an example [https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchcolumn)

Comment: I made the changes but still fail, I have updated my code please take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137113/discussion-between-peter-bruins-and-luke).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a type string instead of type date.use `strtotime()` to convert a string to type date

try this:

```
$date = strtotime($_GET['date']);
```

Comment: Still not getting

Comment: @luke how do the records in the database look? you can try to format `$date` using this syntax `$formatted = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)` but then format it to the format that's in your database

Comment: Still nothing happened

Comment: I have updated my code according to your comments and answer.

Comment: @luke what's the type of RequestDate? string?

Comment: No it's date type